# Angular 7 drag Drop swapping elements

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material

I'm trying to use the new Angular 7 CDK Drag and drop to move a list of elements. But didnt found any option to swap element mostly all the example given are for sorting elements.

https://stackblitz.com/angular/pxgqrvaqbxeg?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.ts

**cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.htm**

```
<div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let movie of movies" cdkDrag>{{movie}}</div>
</div>
```

**cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

/**
 * @title Drag&Drop sorting
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example',
  templateUrl: 'cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.css'],
})
export class CdkDragDropSortingExample {
  movies = [
    'Episode I - The Phantom Menace',
    'Episode II - Attack of the Clones',
    'Episode III - Revenge of the Sith',
    'Episode IV - A New Hope',
    'Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back',
    'Episode VI - Return of the Jedi',
    'Episode VII - The Force Awakens',
    'Episode VIII - The Last Jedi'
  ];

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.movies, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }
}
```

For eg: If drag for element 0 is initiated and dropped at element 4, in that case element 0 dom should be replaced with element 4 and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply swap the item manually:

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    let oldtarget = this.movies[event.previousIndex];
    this.movies[event.previousIndex] = this.movies[event.currentIndex];
    this.movies[event.currentIndex] = oldtarget;
}
```

**<kbd>[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mp5qjp?file=app/cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.ts)</kbd>**

Comment: Your stackblitz its not swapping the items. Its re-ordering.

Comment: I don't buy this answer. While I can intercept and update the logic within the drop event itself and make it work as a swap rather than a re-order, the visible changes during drag are incorrect still and this will be off-putting to users. The "during drag" behaviour should also behave like a swap and not a re-order. In other words the list items below the dragging object should NOT move up/down depending on whether the object being dragged is above or below them.

Answer (score -3):

I don't know if you really checked the Angular Material documentation but here you go:

> [Angular docs (with a lot of sorting examples)](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/examples)

Hope it helped ;)

Comment: ya but i am looking for swapping or replace element not sorting